# $S$ and $Q$ are independent events with $P(S)=0.2$ and $P(Q)=0.3$. What is the probability that at least one of $S$ or $Q$ occurs?

Tags: probability

Assume $S$ and $Q$ are independent events such that:

$P(S)=0.2$
$P(Q)=0.3$

Find the probability of at least one of $S$ or $Q$ occurring.

I tried to solve it by solving it this way:
$P(S \text{ and } Q) + P(S\text{ or }Q)$
 since it says "at least", then I thought it's possible that it could be only one or the two of them would really occur. Though I've also thought that it could be
$P((S \text{ and Not }Q)\text{ or }(Q\text{ and Not }S)) + P(Q\text{ and }S)$. That's why I'm not really sure what to use. I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to solve it by solving it this way: P(S and Q) + P(S or Q) since it says "at least", then I thought it's possible that it could be only one or the two of them would really occur. Though I've also thought that it could be P( S and Not Q or Q and Not S) + P(Q and S). That's why I'm not really sure what to use. I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: what is $P(\bar S)$? Where $\bar S$ is the complementary event of $S$, that is, $S$ does not happen. And what is  $P(\bar Q)$? Are $\bar S$ and $\bar Q$ independent? Are you able to answer these questions @ciarah?

Comment: @ciarah: It's better if you put that context into the original post. Many people will see a bare problem-statement question (PSQ) and down-vote or close-vote it, without looking down at your explanation in the comments.

Comment: alight rewording of my hint: Can you find $P(\text{not }S)$ and $P(\text{not }Q)$? Are $\text{not }S$ and $\text{not }Q$ independent events? What does this tell you about $P(\text{not }S\text{ and not }Q)$? Can you proceed now? @ciarah

Answer (score 1):

The probability of S is 0.2 so the probability S does NOT happen is 0.8.  The probability of Q is 0.3 so the probability Q does NOT happen is .7.
The probability neither S nor Q happens is 0.8(0.7)= 0.56. The probability at least one of S and Q happens is 1- 0.56= 0.44

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$P(\text{at least one of $S$ and $Q$ occurs})\\
=P(S)+P(Q)-P(S\cap Q)\\
=P(S)+P(Q)-P(S)P(Q),$$ since $S$ and $Q$ are independent events.